# DIV element height not growing auto

Tags: html, css

The `DIV` elements `height` is not growing even after I set the `height` property as `auto`.please see the CSS snippet below

```
#main_site {
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center; 
  top: 295px;
  width: 950px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: auto;  
}
```

I have one image in in the content DIV, the image `align` property is `right`, but in IE8, the image showing left.

`<p><img src="images/image.jpg" align="right" hspace="5" alt="images..." />` 
The above code is working fine in Firefox, but NOT working in IE8.

Please correct me if I did any mistake.

Comment: show us html to see how to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding `float:left;` Should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

Like said here, if you have a floated element inside, the div won't gain height. *however*, that doesn't mean you need extra markup.

```
Overflow: hidden;
```

Will force it to recalculate its height. which in turn will cause it to grow as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are the contents of the `#main_site` div floated? If so that could be the problem. You may need to post more HTML/CSS

Answer (score 0):

height:auto only tells the div to set the height to the tallest internal element. If you have floated internal elements, try adding the following right before the close of your #main_site div:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

This will ensure that you #main_site div "wraps" the internal elements.